# windows 10 map bluetooth function key

Tags: windows-10, laptop, keyboard-shortcuts, bluetooth, lenovo-laptop

My new Lenovo laptop (E590) has a bluetooth function key, but it doesn't do anything. How do tell windows 10 to map it to toggling bluetooth, as was undoubtedly the intention?

Comment: Lenovo Bleutooth is part of Wireless on all my Lenovo machines. Is wireless ON?  Is Airplane Mode OFF?  Is there are wireless switch on the side of the laptop (some Lenovo laptops have this). Is the switch ON.  If after all the above, it does not work, contact Lenovo Support. They are very helpful.

Comment: did you install all the drivers? Those keys are not handled by the OS so Windows doesn't know about their existence

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was just missing some extra Lenovo drivers. The [Hotkey Driver](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-edge-laptops/thinkpad-e590-type-20nb-20nc/downloads/DS031814), to be precise. It's weird, I would have expected windows 10 to be smart enough to do this for all laptops. The volume keys were already mapped, for instance.